# Apache Cordova - How do we protect the page after session destroy

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, session

I'm working on the mobile application.

Initially, I'm testing it in the browser.The problem is as follows,

Before session destroys you copied that URL and after that you destroyed that session then again your are opening the browser and typing on the new window. it is working how can we control that functionality in HTML.

I wrote restful web service in java to destroy the session.

Example: login page completed redirecting to Home page(login->Home)
The home page you copied that URL and there we have also logged out functionality.
Again if you copy that home URL it must not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can maintain session even in javascript
http://code.google.com/p/sessionstorage/

Use this above mechanism to maintain sessions in javascript.

It is better than using window.location.href =, because replace() does not put the originating page in the session history, meaning the user won't get stuck in a never-ending back-button fiasco. If you want to simulate someone clicking on a link, use location.href. If you want to simulate an HTTP redirect, use location.replace.
Example:

```
// similar behavior as an HTTP redirect
window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
// similar behavior as clicking on a link
window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
```